# Adding terms to the Lagrangian using quantum numbers (symmetries)

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, notation, representation-theory

The SM is build on $SU(3)_C\times SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$.

Left quarks behave like $Q_l\sim(3,2,1/6)$ (colour triplet, $SU(2)$ doublet and $1/6$ hypercharge)

Or the SM Higgs $\Phi\sim(1,2,1/2)$

Since the Lagrangian is a scalar, $L\sim(1,1,0)$

I understand this numbers, but not how to combine them, for example:

$\bar{l}_L\Phi e_R\sim(1,\bar{2},1/2)(1,2,1/2)(1,1,-1)\sim(1,1,0)$

The hypercharge is simply summed, but what about the $SU(3)_C$ or $SU(2)_L$? (what does $\bar{2}$ means?)

Comment: Tensor-multiplying three color singlets yields a color singlet (colorless trivial irrep). Tensor-multiplying an isodoublet with its conjugate yields an isosinglet, which tensored to an isosinglet, yields an isosinglet. It is not different than addition of two spin 1/2s in elementary QM. Are you comfortable with that? Study up on conjugates.

Comment: That is what I was assuming, but I wasn't sure. Which would be the resoult of $(\bar{3}, \bar{2},-1/6)(1,3,0)(3,1,2/3)$. Is it $(1,2,1/2)$? Not sure about SU(2) term.

Comment: The rest is fine. In principle, the SU(2) term is a $\bar 2$ or a $\bar 4$, depending on the details of the coupling. Looks like homework to me.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_representation#The_SU(2)_and_SU(3)_cases).

Comment: This is a homework exercise, but I do not have a good knowledge of group theory. $(1,3,0)$ is a Higgs triplet theory. I need to add all the possible interaction terms to the Lagrangian.// Not sure if I can find another representation for the field so it is $2$ or $4$. //This is related to the seesaw mechanism for neutrino masses.

Comment: But the color 3s are quarks, not neutrinos (colorless leptons)!?